# How to detect whether my app is loading data, and if so, showing a loading screen

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, screen, loading

I want to implement into my cocos2d project (ipad) a loading screen, whenever data is being fetched. Is there a convenient way to do this without hard-coding it ?

Comment: If you request data it is loading, if you received your response you are not loading. Or are you looking for something readymade?

Comment: no, I just want to know how to detect for instance, if a scene is being loaded, and if so, show a spinning wheel or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag/start an activity indicator/etc. that indicates that the loading has begun at the beginning of the computational process and stop it after the end. Update in the meantime if you intend to add a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this github project.](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) It gives you a framework for detecting when a task that you want to happen is in progress. It also lets you decide what happens when the task is completed.

Comment: we ment to share some description rather than a random link... with no reference description...

Comment: Sorry, I figured that simply checking out the mentioned github project would be enough to solve the problem, but I guess not. I added a short blurb.